# Haskell:create list of last elements of each list in list

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I need to define the function in Haskell's 
which for a given list of lists will create a list of its last elements.
For example for `[[1,2],[3,4]]` it should return `[2,4]`

I tried to use pattern matching but ite returns only the last list :

```
lastElement :: [[a]] -> [a]
lastElement [] = error "error"
lastElement [x] = x
lastElement (x:xs) = lastElement xs
```

it gives me `[3,4]`

Comment: your function just calculates the last element of a single list. That's a good start (although it already exists in the standard library as [last](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:last)). But you need to apply this function to every list in the given list of lists. Hint: Haskell has a built-in way to do this for any function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem

You are on the right track, the problem is that your code is not recursing. A recursive function on lists is usually of the form

```
f :: [a] -> [b]
f [] = y
f (x:xs) = y : f xs
```

After `y` is evaluated, that result is "`:`ed" to the recursive call. Now try to make your code so something similar. Also note that you don't need the `lastElement [x]` case, it's just plain reduntant for the recursion. However, this only applies some function to every element. You will also need a function `f :: [a] -> a` to get that last element from one single list. Your function as of now does just that, but there is a standard library function for that. Have a look at [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle): you can search library functions by type or description

## Better Alternative

In this case, I would use a list comprehension as I think it would be more clear to read. Have a look at that as well

## Best Alternative

Haskell being a functional language, it allows you to think more about what change to need to apply to your data, rather than what steps do you need to achieve. If you know them, you can use higher order function for this. In particular, the function `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. As you can guess from this type definition, `map` takes a function, and applies it to every element of a list. It looks like you already know the `last` function, so you can use that:

```
lastElements :: [[a]] -> [a]
lastElements = map last
```

Look how neat and simple this code is now; no need to think about what the recursion does, you just see that it takes the last element from each list.

Comment: While list recursion usually doesn't need a singleton list case, it does if you want to implement a function to find the last element of a list, which is what the function in the OP does. It's not clear to me if that was the intention or simply an accident,

Comment: @RobinZigmond Good call, but I was just trying to show the most simple but at the same type most generic recursion on lists, so that the OP can try to implement themself as they were quite close already.

Comment: @RobinZigmond oh I see what you mean, I thought they were already using `last` and using recursion just to apply it to every element, my bad. Edited now

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you have beginner skills in Haskell and try to explain better what you are doing wrong.

```
lastElement :: [[a]] -> [a]
lastElement [] = error "error"
lastElement [x] = x
lastElement (x:xs) = lastElement xs
```

In this function, you are receiving a list of elements and returning the last of it. Occurs that those elements are lists too. In that way, applying `lastElement [[1,2],[3,4]]` will give to you his last element how is the list `[3,4]`. Since you need to enter a list `[x,y,z]` in which x y and z are lists and you wanna return `[last of x, last of y, last of z]`, we need two things:

**1.** A function which receives a list of Int and return his last element

**2.** Apply this function to a (list of (lists of a)) **[[a]]**

To make **(1)** we can easily modify your function lastElement just like this:

```
lastElement :: [a] -> a
lastElement [] = error "error"
lastElement [x] = x
lastElement (x:xs) = lastElement xs
```

Now, lastElement receives one list and return its last element.

To make **(2)** we just need to create a mapping function like this:

```
mapping :: ([a] -> a) -> [[a]] -> [a]
mapping _ [] = []
mapping f (x:xs) = (f x) : (mapping f xs)
```

In that way, you can call `mapping lastElement [[1,2],[3,4]]` that will give you `[2,4]`.

I need to say that none of this is needed if you knew two functions which is last who do the same as **(1)** and map who do the same as **(2)**. Knowing this, you can do like [Lorenzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9991455/lorenzo) already done above:

```
lastElements :: [[a]] -> [a]
lastElements = map last
```